# Improve browser autofill functionality in Oracle APEX 5

Tags: oracle-apex, autofill, oracle-apex-5

I want to improve the results from the browser autofill function, which mainly seems to take the `name` attribute of `input` elements into account. As I see it, APEX just numbers them consecutively per form resulting in something like `p_t03`.

With multiple forms the suggestions hardly make sense. So I thought about changing the `name` attribute of the `input` fields to something more meaningful.

A few tests didn't reveal any problems with that. Has any of you tried this before? I'd very much appreciate hints about any problems that might occur or structured approaches. Should I use a Dynamic Action on Page 0 maybe?

Comment: APEX will stop working if you mess with the input names, as they are used in its submit processing.

Comment: Sad to hear that :( do you see any workaround? things will probably be the same with 5.1 I guess...?

Comment: APEX 5.1 seems to bring improvement: _Name attribute of a page item input field is no longer maps to the p_t001 to p_200 parameters and p_v00 to p_v200 parameters of wwv_flow.accept. Instead the Name attribute now contains the page item name._